# How to concatenate two or three arrays together in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

For Example:

if the output is coming like this

```
array([0]=>1) array([0]=>2) array([0]=>3)
```

How to combine them like this:

```
array([0]=>1,[1]=>2,[2]=>3)
```

Thanku very much

Please Guys help me with this problem

Comment: How is the original output generated, it would be better to fix this than process the data a second time.

Comment: Its generated exactly like this array([0]=>1) array([0]=>2) array([0]=>3) but i want in this manner array([0]=>1,[1]=>2,[2]=>3)

Comment: If we can't see the code that produces the original output, we can't tell you how to fix it to produce your desired output...

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha - I was first :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld don't worry I voted up your answer & deleted the comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer based on what you supply:

```
$new_array = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Comment: What if there are an unknown number of elements?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - if the array is in array([0]=>1) array([0]=>2 array([0]=>3 then your method array_merge doesn't work.

Comment: @NigelRen yeah even this question is valid

Comment: @swarajpethkar - I don't understand. Why should it not work? Can you supply your actual array and what you want to do with it? (Edit your question please).

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld sorry buddy my mistake it worked thanku

Comment: No worries! Glad to help!